# Fastforward and rewind of ffmpeg are disabled

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm creating a mp4 (or flv) file using string something like this:

```
ffmpeg -i pipe1file -i pipe2file -c copy -f flv resultFile.flv
```

I recieve the resultant file. But the forward or rewind are seem to be disabled. How to fix it?

Comment: Please add the console output.

Comment: So just a hunch but *if* rew/ff aren't working through a browser and a server under your control, the web server software must have the ability to respond to "partial content" requests.  See [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088364/html5-video-will-not-loop]

Answer (score 0):

If it will help to somebody. I solved this problem by using "-g 25" string.
 "-g" changes GOP for ffmpeg libx264
 https://sites.google.com/site/linuxencoding/x264-ffmpeg-mapping

Comment: Without seeing what the actual input is, this answer isn't really useful, I'm afraid. Especially when you're just doing a stream copy with `-c copy`, setting the GOP will not affect the bitstream in any way.

Comment: @slhck Yes. You are right.